# Design an O( n log n ) algorithm that returns true if greater than half of the addresses in L are generated from the same real IP address

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve this homework problem:

You are working for National Security Agency (NSA). The website of
NSA is under-attack and you are given a list
L
of suspicious IP addresses
from which suspicious activity has been logged. However, these IP ad-
dresses are not real addresses but created by malicious attackers using
some anonymizing software, which hides the real IP address and makes
it seem that the suspicious activity has originated from some fake IP ad-
dresses. The anonymizing software has been developed by an expert pro-
grammer and can create dierent fake IP addresses even when the program
is used multiple times from the same IP address.
A clever colleague of yours has developed a
C
function

SAME_REAL_IP(Addr1,Addr2)

which returns true when the two fake addresses
Addr
1 and
Addr
2 are
generated from the same real IP address and false otherwise. Assuming
that this function takes a constant amount of time to compute, please
design an
O
(
n
log
n
) algorithm that returns true if
>
half of the addresses
in
L
are generated from the same real IP address. You must argue why
your algorithm runs in
O
(
n
log
n
) in order to get full credit.

Here is the algorithm I wrote:

```
algorithm(list L){

    int halfLength = L.length()/2;
    int lengthCounter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < L.length()-1; i++){

        if(SAME_REAL_IP(i, i+1))
            lengthCounter += 1;
    }

    if(lengthCounter > halfLength)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Now, the problem is that my for loop compares each element in the list like this:

SAME_REAL_IP(0,1)
SAME_REAL_IP(1,2)
SAME_REAL_IP(2,3)
SAME_REAL_IP(3,4)
...

But it would never check for something like SAME_REAL_IP(2,7);

While I could do this with nested for loops, it would only run in O(n^2) and I need it to run in O( n log n)

So my question is, how do I check each element with each other in a faster time?

Comment: The last sentance of your question is asking "how can I do an O(n^2) algorithm faster than O(n^2)".  The answer is clearly "You can't".  So the hint is: "Don't check each element with _every_ other element".

Comment: This is a surprisingly hard problem.  I _think_ I have it, but proving it's O(n log n) is hard :/

Comment: The clue is in "please design an O ( n log n ) algorithm that returns true if > half of the addresses in L are generated from the same real IP address". So you not after many fakes from different real addresses but many fakes from the same real address. So you will be building sets of fakes that may merge.

Comment: @Mooing Duck Thanks, I think this might be starting to make a little more sense. So say I started at element 0 and compared it with every other element. I could then conclude that 0 is not fake if it returns false. Then I could compare 1 with all the elements except 0 with the same conclusion, and so on...Which should make the algorithm run in O(n log n) because an element is being eliminated each iteration?

Comment: Nevermind, that is the same thing as nested for loops...

Comment: @Elephant: What I have so far is comparing each element with the one after, and the one two after, which gives you a sequence of "equivalent sets of 2+ keys".  At least 25% of the "true" keys are guaranteed to be in some of those combined sets.  For an O(n log(n)) algorithm, recursion is involved, but each time you recurse you have the possibility of losing _up to_ 75% of the "true keys" from the prior layer, which is pretty lossy.

Comment: There's also many cases to consider: (1) one key used 49%, all others unique.  (2) two keys each use 50%. (3) one key uses 51%, one key uses 49%.  And that's completely ignoring potential pathological distributions.

Comment: On the good news, once you find one or two sets with 25% of the keys, it's linear time to check all other keys against those two sets.  (If you find three or four sets with 25%, then no one set has >50%)

Comment: Thanks! Got it working using a recursive function. :D